# Vector spaces, bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1) In a vector space $V$ of all real polynomials of third degree or less find basis $B$ such that for arbitrary polynomial $p \in V$ the following applies:
$[p]_B = \begin{pmatrix} p'(0)\\p'(1)\\p(0)\\p(0)\end{pmatrix}$ where $p'$ is the derivative of the polynomial $p$.

2)  In a space of real functions we have a subspace defined by the set $V = \langle 1,x, \cos x, \sin x \rangle$ and its subspace defined by the set $W = \{f \in V\mid f(\pi) = 0\}$

Find some basis of $W$.

---

In 2) We can see that the functions $1,x,\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are linearly independent and so form a basis for $V$. Thus, some function in $V$ is of the form

$$ f(x) = a + bx + c \cdot \mathrm{cos}(x) + d \cdot \mathrm{sin}(x) $$

where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. We have $f \in W$ if and only if $f(\pi) = 0$ if and only if

$$ f \left( \pi \right) = a + b \pi -c = 0.$$

This is a linear equation for the coefficients $(a,b,c,d)$ of $f$ whose solution subspace is a three dimensional subspace $W'$ of $V' = \mathbb{R}^4$ given by

$$ W' = \mathrm{span} \{ (0,0,0,1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, \pi, 0 \}. $$

If I now translate this solutions back to $W$, we should get the basis of $W$: 
$$ W = \mathrm{span} \{ \mathrm{sin}(x), 1 + \mathrm{cos}(x), x + \pi \cos(x) \}. $$
Is that correct?

As for 1) I am pretty lost and don't know in which direction to go..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a typo in $[p]_B,$ by chance?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that there is a typo in the given formula for $[p]_B,$ and that it is instead supposed to be something like $$[p]_B=\begin{pmatrix}p(0)\\p(1)\\p'(0)\\p'(\alpha)\end{pmatrix}$$ (where $\alpha$ is some specified non-zero real number). What this means is that we need to find some $q_1(x),q_2(x),q_3(x),q_4(x)\in V$ such that $$p(x)=p(0)q_1(x)+p(1)q_2(x)+p'(0)q_3(x)+p'(\alpha)q_4(x)\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ for any $p(x)\in V.$ To do so, we begin with an arbitrary element of $V,$ say $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d,$ and note the following:

- $p(0)=d$
- $p(1)=a+b+c+d$
- $p'(0)=c$
- $p'(\alpha)=3a\alpha^2+2b\alpha+c$

One way to proceed, then, is to make these substitutions in $(\heartsuit),$ gather like terms to get it in the form $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=a[\text{stuff}_1]+b[\text{stuff}_2]+c[\text{stuff}_3]+d[\text{stuff}_4],$$ then use that to get the system $$\begin{cases}\text{stuff}_1=x^3\\\text{stuff}_2=x^2\\\text{stuff}_3=x\\\text{stuff}_4=1,\end{cases}\tag{$\star$}$$ which we can solve for each $q_j(x).$

Another approach is to instead consider the standard basis $p_0(x)=1,$ $p_1(x)=x,$ $p_2(x)=x^2,$ $p_3(x)=x^3.$ If we figure out how to make $[p_j]_B$ work for $j=0,1,2,$ and $3,$ then we're home free! For example, using $p=p_0$ in $(\heartsuit)$ yields $$1=p_0(x)=p_0(0)q_1(x)+p_0(1)q_2(x)+p_0'(0)q_3(x)+p_0'(\alpha)q_4(x)=q_1(x)+q_2(x),$$ and so $$1=q_1(x)+q_2(x).\tag{0}$$ Similarly we obtain: $$x=q_2(x)+q_3(x)+q_4(x)\tag{1}$$ $$x^2=q_2(x)+2\alpha q_4(x)\tag{2}$$ $$x^3=q_2(x)+3\alpha^2q_4(x)\tag{3}$$

As it turns out, equations $(0)$ through $(3)$ give us exactly the system $(\star)$! Hopefully, they also make clear why I assumed that $\alpha$ was a **non-zero** real.

---

As for part 2: it looks good!